# changing attributes to a JButton created by a method without variable name

Tags: java, methods, jbutton

I create some JButtons with a method, but I don't give them a variable i can call them with. i was  wondering if it is possible to change the text somehow, after the button is created from another method. I am aware of that i can get the action command when the button is pressed but i want to change the button text, without it being pressed. I can give the buttons names like but would prefer not to. since I am only going to call half of them, and then I don't think its a good idea. or is it?

JButton button1 = buttons(0,0,0);

```
    public JButton buttons(int coord, int coord1, int number) {
       JButton box = new JButton("");
       box.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 60));
       box.setBounds(coord, coord1, 100, 100);
       contentPane.add(box);
       box.addActionListener(this);
       box.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(number));

       return box;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    buttons(0,0,0);
    buttons(98,0,1);
    buttons(196,0,2);
    buttons(0,98,3);
    addText();
}

public void addText() {
//help me guys
button.setText("Please fix me");
}
```

Comment: `i was wondering if it is possible to change the text somehow, after the button is created from another method` Of course you can, so long you keep a reference of the buttons you created. I don't see a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pressed button from actionEvent

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();

    }
```

Comment: "I am aware of that i can get the action command when the button is pressed but i want to change the button text, without it being pressed."

So that will require me to press the button :/

Comment: I think that you can somehow get list of buttons from panel or frame, But anyway you need some identifier to differentiate buttons

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have them in a public arraylist?

```
ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

public JButton buttons(int coord, int coord1, int number) {
   JButton box = new JButton("");
   box.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 60));
   box.setBounds(coord, coord1, 100, 100);
   contentPane.add(box);
   box.addActionListener(this);
   box.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(number));
   buttons.add(box);//Add it here
   return box;
}
```

This way you can loop through them later and change something if you want to,

```
for(JButton b : buttons){
  if(/*Whatever*/){
    b.setText("New name");
  }
}
```

Comment: "I am only going to call half of them"

is it possible to only change some specific with this method?

Comment: That's why I wrote the if statement, you can make sure that you're modifying only the JButtons you want to

Answer (score 0):

> I can give the buttons names like but would prefer not to. since I am only going to call half of them, and then I don't think its a good idea. or is it?

You are creating problems for yourself. Even if you may only need the call a few/none of them, there is significant advantage for not keeping a reference for them.

If you have too many JButtons and you do not want to have a separate variable name for each of them, you can have an array/collection of JButtons.

```
JButton[] btns = new JButton[size];
//or
ArrayList<JButton> btns= new ArrayList<JButton>();
```

**To change text for all buttons:**

```
for(JButton b : btns)
    btns.setText("whatever here");
```

**To change text for a specific button:**

```
btns[x].setText("whatever here");       //from array
btns.get(x).setText("whatever here");   //from list
```

---

Alternatively, if you do not keep a reference. You can get the list of buttons from the content pane:

```
Component[] components = myPanel.getComponents();    
for(Component c : components)
    if(c instanceof JButton)
        ((JButton)c).setText("whatever here");
```

Comment: @Bug I would say whether we can make it work or not will depend on your coding skill (i.e. how we implement it).

Comment: Of course it's possible, but ArrayList were created so we wouldn't have to append to definite Array[]'s array time using something such as Arrays.copyOf

Comment: @Bug Actually if you want to dynamically remove or add swing components to your panel, it can exhibit risky behaviours. Most of the time, the number of components such as number of buttons can be predetermined when we create the GUI. It is not always necessary to use an ArrayList. Tell me, how many of the swing applications you created need arbitrary number of components?

Comment: @Bug `Not really, he's not adding the JButtons all at once so Arrays wouldn't work..` You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: It's terrible coding ethic to rely on a specific numbers of components every time you create a swing application.

Comment: @Bug I didn't say everytime. Terrible coding ethic? Wow, looks like even the oracle developers have a lot to learn from you. Please read up more before commenting. I don't want to talk anything more. No point explaining to someone full of himself. Looks like I've been talking to someone who will write 10,000 lines of code for a "hello world" program.